# Android increase space between words

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am working on android app that contain table and rows. In each row there will be three values. The problem is these values are so close to each other and I want to increase the space between them so each one will be above its column, like this:

[image]

but it is displayed like this:

[image]

here is the table layout in the xml file:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="name"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="email"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="password"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

  </TableRow>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="get user info"/>
 </TableLayout>
```

and this the information of the user in the Java file:

```
 String userData =  "" + Html.fromHtml(userName + userEmail + userPassword );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single `TextView` with all the strings concatenated, just add a second `TableRow` containing three separate `TextView` controls, just like the first one.

That way they should be similarly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

an updated code here:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="email"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="password"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

 </TableRow>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="get user info"/>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="get user info"/>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="get user info"/>
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

So this will align every item in the Table Layout with each view. A good way of thinking about it is that you're creating a n X n matrix.